# HMS Toolkit Android Studio failed to initialize

Tags: android-studio, plugins, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

After I install the plugin HMS Toolkit, the problem comes out when I restart Android Studio, anyone knows the reason of it? My version is 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently HMS Toolkit is only supported on these Android Studio versions: 3.3.2 to 4.0.1 [Documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881)

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) is the link to download an old version of android

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Android Studio versions 3.3.2 to 4.1 are [supported](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050060881__section115911642133417?ha_source=hms1).

---

1. Currently, Android Studio versions 3.3.2 to 4.0.1 are supported.
2. The compatibility of HMS Toolkit has been modified. The new version will be released in early November.

For more details, you can go to the official website [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881?ha_source=hms1).

Answer (score 0):

HMS Core Tool Kit is a plug-in Installed in Android studio to facilitate app creation, coding, conversion, debugging, testing and release.  It helps to integrate HMS Core API in the most efficient way and at the lowest possible cost.
Current version of HMS Tolkit is **3.0.2.301** and released on 2020-09-11

For suppting HMS Toolkit You have to check the following criteria

**Supported Android Studio Versions:** Android Studio versions 3.3.2 to 4.0.1 are supported.

**Supported Operating Systems:** This tool is tested in Windows 10, macOS 10.12/10.13/10.14, and Ubuntu 16.04/14.04.

**Supported Android Studio UI Themes:** Windows: Darcula/IntelliJ
macOS: Darcula/Default